# JQuery getScript() calling anonymous function from curl.js module

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl, module, anonymous-function

I have a Curl.js module defined as:

```
define("Portfolio", ["jquery"], function(jquery) {
var $ = jquery;

var Portfolio = (function() {
    $("#output").text("Getting Stuff");
    var name = "";
    var holdings = [];

    return {
        "stupid": function() {
            $.getScript("app/myScript.js", function(dog) {
                //var dog = new Dog();
                dog.speak();
            }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                console.log(exception);
            });
        }
    }
})();

return Portfolio;
});
```

/app/myScript.js looks like this:

```
(function() {

var breed = "Poodle";
return {
    speak: function() {
        alert("Woof");
    }
};
})();
```

I am calling the "stupid" method from the console in Chrome as follows:

```
curl(['Portfolio'], function(Portfolio){
Portfolio.stupid();
});
```

And Chrome says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object (function() {

var breed = "Poodle";
return {
    speak: function() {
        alert("Woof");
    }
};
})(); has no method 'speak'
```

In myScript.js i could use `var Dog = (function(){....})();` which would work but I don't want to pollute the global namespace that way.

I could also use `function Dog(){....}` and in my getScript callback use `new Dog().speak()` but then Dog wont be a module in that I would have private properties, and it would also be bound to the global scope.

It seems that $.getScript() does not bind the returned value of the script called to any variable that is accessible form the callback function of getScript(); at least none that I could find.  It does return data but that is only the text of the script called.  I did find a cheat that I can take the returned script and run it through `eval()`.  Oddly this is pretty much exactly what $.getScript() method itself does.  Reworking the Stupid method to the following code:

```
"stupid": function() {
    $.get("/app/myScript.js", function(Dog) {
        var dog = new (eval(Dog));
        console.log("Breed:" + dog.getBreed());
        d.setBreed("Lab");
        console.log("Breed: " + dog.getBreed());
    });
}
```

This does work but it feels a bit hacky and wrong.

How can I use getScript() to call /app/myScript.js that is written as a module or anonymous self-executing function and then call one of the returned functions?  getScript is supposed to execute the script which I thought, as I have it written, return an object bount to the getScript return object that I could then call?  Obviously I am missing something here.

Why you no work Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

if once you use curl.js maybe it is better to forget about JQuery.getScript()
read curl's wiki!